# Que veut dire IA ?

Tags: sens, travail

En remplissant des dossiers de compétences pour une recherche d’emploi plusieurs sociétés mettent le signe IA à remplir.

Que veut dire IA ?

[image]

--

[image]

Comment: Seraitil possible d'avoir un lien vers le contexte ?

Comment: je crois pas, j'ai modifié la question, j'ai ajouté un autre cas, ils sont tous pareil

Comment: Selon le contexte ça peut vouloir dire beaucoup de chose je pense, pour une personne, Ingénieur d'Affaire ou Ingénieur d'Armement peut être ? (Sinon l'utilisation la plus commune est Intelligence artificielle mais ça parait peut pertinent ici)

Comment: oui Ingénieur d'affaire parait plus logique, merci pour l'idée

Comment: Encore une fois, je déteste les acronymes. Je n'aurais pas trouvé non plus, même avec le contexte. Pour moi, c'est _intelligence artificielle_…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le contexte de [Astek](http://fr.viadeo.com/fr/jobs/ingenieur-d-affaires-h-f-00213it7szztnmk0), comme le dit @servabat, *Ingénieur d'Affaire* est le sens le plus probable. C'est généralement la personne à contacter pour un certain type de projet, ce qui correspond aussi au premier contexte.